# Use IDE instead of QGIS Processing Script Editor

Tags: pyqgis

Having opened an arbitrary myproject.qgz in a QGIS window, I load a raster.tif into the project from the Python Script Editor as follows:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from qgis.utils import iface
iface.addRasterLayer(QgsProject.instance().readPath("./") + "/raster.tif", "Raster Layer")
```

How can I run this script from an external IDE (given that its environment variables are configured correctly), i.e. load and show the raster in the open myproject.qgz?

Comment: I guess (not sure 100%), QGIS doesn't support such a functionality (interfering from outside).